# Scala dummy Future not completed

Tags: scala, testing, future

I'm pretty new to Scala and I'd like to know if there's some way to create a dummy `Future` object to simulate `isCompleted` to `false`. I need this for testing purposes.

Currently what I'm using to have a dummy `Future[Int]` is this:

```
Future({
    while (true) {}
    1
})
```

which is very ugly.

**EDIT**
I have an `object` with a variable `x` which is a `Option[Future[Int]]`. In the same `object` I have method that checks whether `x` is different from `None`, and if it is it checks whether it is completed or not. If the future is not completed yet it avoids calling a method on an external helper object. This external helper object during testing is mocked and I'm checking that it is not being called. To achieve this I currently set the `x` variable to the `Future` written above.

Comment: why can't you use Future.successful(1) for that purpose.

Comment: and make the question more clear it's too general. what kind of testing you are doing and what exectly you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Future.never`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/concurrent/Future$$never$.html), also suggested first by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52078150/152602):

```
val f: Future[Int] = Future.never
```

You should avoid using a promise (as this answer initially suggested):

```
val f: Future[Int] = Promise[Int]().future
```

since it can lead to memory leaks if the future is subscribed to, see [here](https://viktorklang.com/blog/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-6.html) for a description.

Comment: `Future.never` is a better solution because it makes the purpose clear.

Comment: Please never do that—you see, all callbacks will be added and you'll silent leak memory until that Future is no longer referenced anywhere. Use Future.never instead. Read more about it here: https://viktorklang.com/blog/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-6.html

Answer (score 5):

Also, there is simple:

```
val f: Future[Int] = Future.never
```